Google Colab mostly blocking an Oauth call
I am using Google's Colab notebooks for some python scratch.
I noticed that when I do an auth refresh on an API it works at first, but then 403s every time thereafter.  Running the same code locally 200s fine.
I couldn't find any documentation online, but I'm wondering if Colab doesn't play nicely on token exchanges because of its protected local storage. Is there a workaround I should be considering?
import json, requests

auth_url = 'https://www.strava.com/oauth/token?'

params = {
    'client_id': cid
    ,'client_secret': csecret
    ,'grant_type': 'refresh_token'
    ,'refresh_token': strava_refresh_token
}

response = requests.post(auth_url, data=params)
#auth_response = json.loads(response.content)

print(response.status_code)


Never post pictures of code. Always share real code. incredibly annoying for someone who wants to use your code and alter it to answer your question. Refresh tokens are single-use usually. Are you updating strava_refresh_token for subsequent uses?

swapped in code

Strava's API you use a combination of client info plus a stable refresh token, this returns a single-use token for actual downstream use.  Re-running the code multiple times on local works fine.

Oh that's a bit unusual! So the result of the post request you're doing doesn't give you a fresh refresh token? that's the normal OAuth2 flow!

Checking the documentation, maybe this is not true: https://developers.strava.com/docs/authentication/#refreshingexpiredaccesstokens
